# How to import a Processing file into a Processing file?

Tags: java, import, processing, processing-ide

I am making a Java Processing project in Processing IDE and would like to spread it across multiple PDE (Processing Source Code) files.

I am unable to import Java Processing Source Code file as a Java class file using `import`.

`config.pde`

```
public int screenWidth = 750;
```

`project.pde`

```
import project.config;
// OR
import project.config.screenWidth;
// OR
import config;
// OR
import config.screenWidth;
```

returns `The import project/config cannot be resolved.` respectively.

Do I have to compile PDE files first? Can I set up the Processing IDE to do it automatically for every run?

---

**TLDR;**

Having this project folder:

```
|project
|--project.pde
|--config.pde
```

How do I use functions and variables from `config.pde` in `project.pde`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In general:**

The Processing IDE may support multiple tabs but these do not behave like Java classes: every tab is a member of the same higher-level class behind the scenes. As a result, all members from all tabs share the same scope and a tab that declares a given primitive, object, method or class needn't be referenced when another tab accesses a member from it.

For this reason, declaring a member `private` in one tab will not reduce accessibility of it in other tabs; every declaration is effectively public, for they reside within the same outer-class scope.

`import` is only required when you wish to introduce and reference external libraries.

**In your project:**

Simply refer to `screenWidth` within the *project.pde* tab to access it. The same can be said for any methods you wish to reference between tabs.